# programatically create horizontal slide view controller transition in ios

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, uimodaltransitionstyle

I would like to use **horizontal slide** view controller transition without implementing navigation view controller. Under `modalTransitionStyle` property I only found the CoverVertical, CrossDisolve, ParticalCurl, FlipHorizontal and RawValue (which I don't know what is means) options. Is it possible to use horizontal slide without UINavigationViewController? If it is, how?

Current code:

```
  let mapViewController = story.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("nearbyVC") as! MapViewController
  mapViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
  self.showViewController(mapViewController, sender: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ended up using navigation view controller and hiding navigation bar. It really isn't a problem implementing a navigation controller.

Answer (score -2):

Try this

let mapViewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("PLoginVC") as! PLoginVC
                mapViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.CoverVertical
                self.presentViewController(mapViewController, animated: true, completion: { () -> Void in
                })

Comment: Thanks for stopping by. Cover vertical is not desired. horizontal slide is what I am after.